# Master Data Services 2016 data validation: Must be unique in combination

Tags: validation, service, unique, master-data-services

When I save my 'Must be unique in combination with following attributes' with 1, 2 or 3 other attributes, Master Data only saves the first attribute, as I had only choose a 'Must be unique independently'. 
Any idea? Bug in MDS 2016 SP1? 
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I have the same problem, it was working on an old business rule, but I needed to delete it for update purposes. I am trying to put the rule back but I get the same error...

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I feel less alone with this incredible problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3112582

Microsoft tell us:

The fix for this issue is included in the following updates:

- SQL Server 2016 SP1 MDS GDR https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3210089
- ... (I am limited with max 2 links in my answer!!!! grrrr)
- ...

I installed the KB and I upgraded my MDS database.

It solved all my problems with Business Rules :-)